# How do I make a text field editable when the app is designed to autofill OTP SMS?

Tags: android, api-reversing

Hello fellow rev engineers,

I'm running an app in an emulator and the problem is that for registration it must autofill the OTP sent by SMS, the text field isn't editable/clickable and I can't advance from this stage.

I looked through the activity code and tried to add attributes like android:clickable=true, visibility, input text, etc to no avail. The field remains greyed out and simply wants to autofill.

What's a  trick up your sleeve to get past this?

Here's the code for reference:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.app.TextView android:textSize="@dimen/reg_title_size" android:textColor="@color/register_title_color" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="30.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="30.0dip" android:text="@string/register_active_service_label" app:text_font="@string/font_bold" />
            <com.app.TextView android:textSize="@dimen/reg_subtitle_size" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="30.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="15.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="30.0dip" android:text="@string/register_insert_info" app:text_font="@string/font_regular" />
    ------> <com.components.edittext.XEditText android:textSize="@dimen/reg_editbox_size" android:textColor="@color/black" android:textColorHint="#ff6d6d6d" android:id="@id/key" android:tag="binding_2" android:background="@color/edittext_bg_color" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="35.0dip" android:layout_marginLeft="40.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="80.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="40.0dip" android:hint="@string/hint_entry" android:textAlignment="center" app:edit_font="@string/font_regular" app:regex="@string/regex_alphanumeric" />
            <com.app.TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="@color/gray" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="40.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="40.0dip" android:text="@string/keyconfirmation_helper_msg" app:text_font="@string/font_condensed_italic" />
            <com.app.TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="@color/gray" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/trysLeftlbl" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="40.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="40.0dip" app:text_font="@string/font_condensed_italic" />
            <com.app.TextView android:textSize="@dimen/reg_subtitle_size" android:textColor="@color/blue_button" android:id="@id/requestNewSmsBtn" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="30.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="30.0dip" android:text="@string/request_new_sms" android:textAlignment="center" app:text_font="@string/font_regular" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of modifying the UI you could try to simulate reception of the SMS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489716/can-i-send-sms-received-intent