# How do i set these tricky boolean values to true in Smali-Dalvik?

Tags: android, dalvik

These would allow me to make the input text field clickable and editable but the thing is how to do this.

Instance field

```
.field private g:Z
```

1 -

```
 invoke-virtual {p1, p2, v0}, Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;->getBoolean(IZ)Z

move-result p2

invoke-virtual {p0, p2}, Lcom/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText;->setTextInputLayoutFocusedRectEnabled(Z)V
```

2 - Which call this one:

```
.method public setTextInputLayoutFocusedRectEnabled(Z)V
.locals 0

iput-boolean p1, p0, Lcom/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText;->g:Z

return-void
```

.end method

Comment: That depends on the way how the developer of the app prevents editing of the field. Therefore I would first start by checking stackoverflow.com how to make a field non-editable (you may end up e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4297763/150978). Then check the app code if it uses this way of making the field non-editable and thus you know what to change. BTW: There was a very similar question yesterday: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/31748/1848 If it wa screated by you please don't create a new account every day...

Comment: BTW: The description of `setTextInputLayoutFocusedRectEnabled` sounds more like an "style option" without an effect of the ability to focus a field or not. It is just if there is a rectangle drawn if the field is focused.